# Overflow:hidden - How does it actually work?

Tags: css

`overflow:hidden` hides content as we all know but is that hidden content still executed ?

For example: if I use `overflow:hidden` to "hide" an ad banner that counts impressions, will impressions still count when banner is hidden?

I will use JavaScript to slide some affiliate banners on page refresh, impressions don't matter really, but would like to understand more of CSS.

Thanks.

Comment: `will impressions still count when banner is hidden?` Sure. The area is clipped, but that doesn't mean the content in it isn't loaded.

Comment: It depends on *how* you count the impressions, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`overflow:hidden` hides the portion of the element. But the elements in that portion are still rendered by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Another use of the *overflow:hidden;* is:

When his childs are floated. It means that they are out of the natural flux of the elements. The consequence is that the container doesn't have height so if you want **to recalculate** the height after elements are positioned including floating elements. In that case you would use *overflow:hidden;*

- Problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kWTgq/

CSS:
    #container {
        background: orange;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

```
#container p {
    float: left;
}
```

- Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kWTgq/1/
- Wrong solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kWTgq/2/

  .clear {
      clear: both;
  }

Comment: And how, pray tell, does this answer the question?

Comment: OMG, I didn't understand the question he ask :-O

Comment: It doesn't. But it's useful to me as I was always used the `wrong solution`
But is this solution "safe"? I mean is it compatible to all browsers?